# How to get rid of highcharts series label

Tags: highcharts

I have been looking at the different options to figure out how to remove the series label that are red circle in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGg9b.jpg)

Comment: Welcome on SO, please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Hi curiousGeorge, you can post this type of questions on: https://forum.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enabled property for series label or do not use series-label.js module.

```
series: [{
  label: {
    enabled: false
  },
  data: [1, 2, 3]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jaL5zev4/